# How to take all files from a folder as input (one at a time) and save them into another folder after processing? (using powershell)

Tags: python, powershell

I have a `.py` script which takes one `.csv` at a time and pre-process it. I am running the command in this way in ***PowerShell***:

`python3 cleaning_script.py file1.csv results_file1.csv`. It works completely fine. There are 300+ files in a folder which I have to pre-process, is there a better way (Loop maybe, but I don't know how to use loop in this environment) in which I can mention the folder and each file is taken as input from the source folder and pre-processed files is saved in the destination folder?

Because of the non-administrative rights in the system (Windows 10), I am using PowerShell to execute the commands.

Comment: I didn't mean to repost a question; just changing the TAGs of the previous one was enough. Also, from the RStudio Terminal doc: `The RStudio terminal provides access to the system shell from within the RStudio IDE`; which means that it uses the native terminal of the OS. I'm not sure that on Windows it is PowerShell, It could also be DOS.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you. I guess I've found a solution, thanks to your suggestion I looked it up for Powershell, got to know how it works and its been working fine. Should I delete this question or post my answer here?

Comment: Glad that you resolved your problem. I’m not sure about what you should do next. The PowerShell question is somewhat trivial but its interesting to know that RStudio is using PowerShell on Windows (instead of DOS)

Comment: Anyway, thanks to you for poiting out my root problem, did some work and got it resolved :)

Comment: You can get a 'file array' with Get-ChildItem (short: gci). This you can pipe and loop through it with a foreach-object. This would be something like `Get-ChildItem foldername | Foreach-Object {script.py $_ }`
A bit more performant is saving the gci output to a variable (`$vars = Get-ChildItem foldername`) and then using `Foreach` to loop through them. `foreach ($var in $vars) {script.py $var}`.
If I understand your question correctly, that is...